# Extract sinusoid from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cross-correlation

I have this image:

[image]

The interface between the gray area in the bottom part and the noisy part in the middle form a somewhat sinusoidal curve. My problem is how do I extract a vector of the same length as the width of the image describing the sinusoidal curve.

So far I have tried xcorr each column of the image to the next column and use cumsum to construct a curve but I havent been successful yet.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Matlab, but this might give you an idea and must be pretty easy to translate - just done in the Terminal with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick sinusoid.png -fill magenta -fuzz 5% -opaque "gray(128)" -fill yellow +opaque magenta result.png
```

[image]

That says... *"Fill with magenta anything within 5% of mid-grey (128) and then fill with yellow anything that is not magenta."*

Of course you might do some morphological closing of holes and edge detection as well. Or scan upwards from the bottom of each column till you encounter yellow.

Comment: Yes I ended up using that approach. I then made a for loop over each column containing a for loop for each row, moving from the bottom of the image and up, creating the vector from the row of the first "yellow" pixel encountered and breaking the nested loop.